# Replacing 170mm cranks with 175mm

Tags: crankset

I have two bikes and one has a broken crank. The broken crank is 170mm and the cranks on my other bike are 175mm. Would I be able to use the 175mm cranks on my other bike to replace the cranks on the broken bike?

Comment: This is almost completely incomprehensible! Please can you edit it to use reasonable English grammar and spelling and try to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: I can't tell if you're serious or not.  Your text is nearly unintelligible.  But the answer to the question (close as I can understand it) is *maybe*.  Depending on a number of factors you may be able to get a new BB cartridge that is 5mm longer or shorter than the old one to work.

Comment: I think he is asking if he can use a 175 length crank arm instead of a 170. The short answer is yes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby   +1 to you for the edit.  Now its pretty clear what is being asked,

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Keith. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking see [ask] also.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think 170/175 represents a bottom bracket size as others have assumed. That would be a very wide axle for a bottom bracket. 170/175 would be the measure of the crank arm length. The crank arm length is pretty much completely a non-issue  except that longer crank arms can cause issues if you pedal through turns.

When looking to replace your crankset or bottom bracket, there are many other things you must look into such as:

1. The bottom bracket spindle length
2. The bottom bracket to frame interface type (English Vs. Italian Vs. various press fit standards)
3. Bottom bracket to crank arm interface type (Square taper, powerspline, ISIS Spline, Octalink, etc.)

If this all sounds like gibberish to you, bring the bike into your local bike store and they can help you out on exactly which parts you will need to replace.